# Reusing a GraphQL query in another query without duplicating

Tags: graphql

Say I have two GraphQL queries.

Query A:

```
{
  entry(section: [privacyStatement]) {
    ... on PrivacyStatement {
      title
      slug
      pageTitle
      metaDescription
      metaImage {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query B:

```
{
  entry(section: [contact]) {
    ... on Contact {
      title
      slug
      pageTitle
      metaDescription
      metaImage {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want both queries to contain another query:

Query C:

```
  {
    services: categories(groupId: 1, level: 1) {
      id
      title
      slug
      children {
        id
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I do that without duplicating query C in both query A and B (which would not be very DRY)? You can only use fragments for pieces within one query if I understand correctly.

Update:

So I mean something like this:

```
Query A {
  entry(section: [privacyStatement]) {
    ... on PrivacyStatement {
      title
      slug
      pageTitle
      metaDescription
      metaImage {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
QueryC
```

and:

```
Query B {
  entry(section: [contact]) {
    ... on Contact {
      title
      slug
      pageTitle
      metaDescription
      metaImage {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
QueryC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define fragments on Query and Mutations and use them like this:

```
Query A {
  entry(section: [privacyStatement]) {
    ... on PrivacyStatement {
      title
      slug
      pageTitle
      metaDescription
      metaImage {
        id
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
  ...C
}

fragment C on Query {
  services: categories(groupId: 1, level: 1) {
    id
    title
    slug
    children {
      id
      title
      slug
    }
  }
}
```

You can not define something like this tho!

```
query A(...){...}
query B(...){...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'm not sure this covers what I mean. What I meant is, is there a way to re-use Query C within Query A and Query B, without adding Query C explicitly to Query A and B. I've updated the question.

Comment: :D Thank you. I'll just have to repeat the query then.